# How to patch each environment only within another environment?

Tags: environments, xpatch

I know how to patch environments using xpatch. But is there a way to patch environments only within a certain environment? For example, all `tabular`s only within `sidewaystable`?

Comment: Sure. You can patch the `sidewaystable` environment to include the code patching `tabular`. The patches are applied locally so the end of `sidewaystable` will revert the `tabular`.

Comment: @Skillmon Perfect. I wouldn't have thought but should have tried patching like that.